# HTML TextArea is not editable in safari but is editable in other browsers

Tags: html, safari

Here is my html for the TextArea:

```html
<textarea class="form__text_area" name="component_corners" id="component_corners" cols="30" rows="10" draggable="true" placeholder="Paste the component's polygon corners here. Example:     [{&quot;Latitude&quot;: 46.75724,&quot;Longitude&quot;: -0.35595}, {&quot;Latitude&quot;: 46.75725,&quot;Longitude&quot;: -0.35575}]  Make sure that the format is correct otherwise the server will return an ERROR!"></textarea>
```

The text needs to be editable, but while in safari I am not able to edit the text. Can someone explain to me why safari is causing this issue? It works perfectly fine on chrome.

EDIT: What is even weirder is that when I quickly switch away and back to the tab with the TextArea on it, I am able to type a single character into the text box, then it becomes uneditable again.

Comment: A `<textarea>` is an interactive form-element editable by users by default, what made you add `contenteditable` to it?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I added content editable to it because of the issue I was having with safari, it wasn't there before

Comment: Agree with the above. contenteditable attribute makes an element like a div editable, that isn't editable normally. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content and in fact contenteditable is not a valid attribute of a textarea: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea

Comment: I wonder if your placeholder code needs to be properly escaped? Try the MDN example in safari and if it works you will know it's one of your code attributes causing the issue.

Comment: @NathanielFlick The MDN example works in safari, I tried deleting some of the attributes and testing it but no luck. I also deleted the content editable attribute but fo course it still doesn't work.

Comment: @LarryYourWaiter can you try it without any JS being applied to it? You could recreate the mdn example on your site and test side by side.

Comment: @NathanielFlick I put the MDN side by side to my TextArea so the MDN example had  the same JS applied to it and still worked, but I'll try using mine without JS.

EDIT: doesn't work even without any JS attached to it.

Comment: What does your html look like, particularly are you declaring html5 doctype?

Comment: @NathanielFlick Yes I have declared the doctype as html5, would you like to see my entire code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234451/discussion-between-larryyourwaiter-and-nathaniel-flick).